# How can I customize an embedded Vimeo video player?

Tags: javascript, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I’m developing a portfolio site that requires a custom Vimeo player, with a play button, pause button, mute button, timer, and progress bar.[This](https://www.eriksaltzman.online/) website has a perfect example of what I would need (just with different CSS).

I’m assuming that within the Vimeo player for whatever video is embedded, there is a piece of data (please forgive/correct my terminology) that corresponds to the play state, pause state, volume, and time that the video has played, which I would then link to with a Javascript event to toggle each of those for the play, pause, and mute buttons. Though from poring over the source code of the above site, and searching for online solutions, I haven't been able to figure out where that information lives.

In short, does this seem like the simplest way to achieve the effect, and if so, how would I get access to the "play state"?

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk and https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/